# Prism MVVM Navigate Command

Tags: mvvm, prism

I've viewed webinar "MVVM Made Simple with Prism" (Brian Lagunas). 
    I      followed his examples to create a main window with a menu with some 
    items. When operator select an item I've to open a view. Application 
    compiled and start but when I select an item nothing happen. 
    I've put some breakpoints to control that view to be opened was 
    istantiated, to control the correct uri and the correct key used in 
    extension RegisterTypeForNavigation. All appear correct. I've noticed that 
    when I select an item from the menu when I close the MainWindow application 
    don't stop automatically. I copy some strings of code to give you more 
    details...

**Main windows xml (MenuPrincipale.xml)**

```
    <Window x:Class="PBEdPallets.Views.MenuPrincipale"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PBEdPallets.Views"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Menu Principale:" Height="600" Width="850">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu Grid.Row="0" x:Name="MenuItems" Height="19" Margin="5,5,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="Anagrafiche">
            <MenuItem Header="Materiali" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="Editor_AnaMateriali"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Sottocataste" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="Editor_AnaSottocataste"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Tipi livelli pile" Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter="Test"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>

    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion" />
</Grid>
```

** Bootstrapper.cs **

```
    using Prism.Unity;
    using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
    using PBEdPallets.Views;
    using System.Windows;

    namespace PBEdPallets
    {
    public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
    {
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        //Importo la finestra di avvio.
        return Container.Resolve<MenuPrincipale>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();

        //Container.RegisterType(typeof(object), typeof(Editor_AnaMateriali), "Editor_AnaMateriali");
        //Container.RegisterType(typeof(object), typeof(Editor_AnaSottocataste), "Editor_AnaSottocataste");

        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<Editor_AnaMateriali>("Editor_AnaMateriali");
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<Editor_AnaSottocataste>("Editor_AnaSottocataste");
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<Test>("Test");
    }
}

public static class UnityExtensions
{
    public static void RegisterTypeForNavigation<T>(this IUnityContainer container, string name)
    {
        container.RegisterType(typeof(object), typeof(T), name);
    }
}
```

}

** MenuPrinciapaleViewModel **

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Prism.Commands;
    using Prism.Mvvm;
    using Prism.Regions;

    namespace PBEdPallets.ViewModels
    {
    public class MenuPrincipaleViewModel: BindableBase  
{
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;
    public DelegateCommand<string> NavigateCommand { get; set; }

    #region Costruttore

    public MenuPrincipaleViewModel(IRegionManager regionalManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionalManager;
        //Definisco l'istanza di NavigateCommand.
        NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(Navigate);
    }

    #endregion Costruttore

    #region Private Methods
    private void Navigate(string uri)
    {
        try
        {
            //ContentRegion è il nome assegnato nel tag ContentControl
            _regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative));
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    #endregion Private Methods
}
```

}

Comment: I've found the error myself: I navigate to a Window object. Changing it to user control I've solved.

Comment: Either delete the question or post a proper answer on how you solved the problem elaborately and chose your answer as the correct answer.